# How can I force this media.net ad code javascript not to execute based on screen size?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, media-queries

I have tried all sorts of things to get this to work. Being that I am not an experienced JS coder, I am pretty sure this is something simple to fix. I am just not able to connect the dots. All I want to do is to let this ad code load on screen sizes larger than 540px, but anything smaller I want to essentially stop the code from executing. If I simply remove the variables on the ELSE section it still executes the ad code. How can I restructure this code to make it load above 540px and for it to be ignored on smaller screen sizes. Keep in mind that the linked script is required for the ad to load.

```
    <script id="mNCC" language="javascript">
        if (window.innerWidth >= 540) {
        medianet_width='468';
        medianet_height= '60';
        medianet_crid='1000000';

        } else {
        medianet_width='180';
        medianet_height= '150';
        medianet_crid='1000000';
//I want NOTHING to happen HERE
        }
        </script><script id="mNSC" src="http://contextual.media.net/nmedianet.js?cid=100000" language="javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the script tag dynamically.

```
<script id="mNCC" language="javascript">
        if (window.innerWidth >= 540) {
        medianet_width='468';
        medianet_height= '60';
        medianet_crid='1000000';
        var my_script = document.createElement('script'); 
        my_script.setAttribute('src','http://contextual.media.net/nmedianet.js?cid=100000'); 
        my_script.setAttribute('id', 'mNSC');
        document.head.appendChild(my_awesome_script);
    } else {
        //remove this if not needed
        medianet_width='180';
        medianet_height= '150';
        medianet_crid='1000000';
    }
</script>
```